# Flutter Dialog box while passing and fetching value Its changing caller form value

Tags: flutter, dialog

I am facing issue while passing and fetching value to dialog box as its replacing the value of caller page directly

```
_MyDialog(
                  cities: allCities,
                  selectedCities: selectedCities1,
                  onSelectedCitiesListChanged: (cities) {
                  print(selectedCities1);
                  });
```

Here selectedCities1 getting change automatically to the same value as selectedCities when we return from Mydialog

Please suggest some solution

Comment: Try to add full code,like  that class where you arrived with this problem.